# External hard drive not playing nice with usb hub

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive

I have just purchased a new USB hub and am having issues getting it to work with my external hard drive.  When I first plugged in the external hard drive, I received an error message stating it needed to be formatted, then the external disappeared.  (I had the external hard drive plugged into my old USB hub with no issues.)  I took the external to a different computer and formatted it, but it still will not show up.  The USB hub is powered, as was the old one.  In case it matters, the only other thing plugged into the USB hub is my keyboard/mouse receiver.  Any ideas or suggestions on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

Comment: First is the hard drive a 2.5" or 3.5" drive.  If it is 3.5" your hub will likely not be able to power it.  Does you external hdd have its own power supply?

Comment: Whether the drive is plugged into a USB port on the computer or a powered hub, the power available at a single USB port is often not sufficient for a hard drive, particularly a larger one.  You often need a "Y" connector, which supplements power from a second USB port, or the drive can be powered from its own power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Many external hard drives have fairly hefty power draw over the USB connector.  You mentioned that your USB hub is powered, but I've seen some that still do not provide enough power to run an external HDD.  Does the HDD work if you plug it straight into the computer?  Does the external Hard Drive have a separate power cord or is it powered completely over USB?

It's also possible that the external HDD is formatted in a format that your computer can't recognize.  For example, if it were formated in EXT4 it wouldnt be recognized on Windows without additional tools.